# How do I add this API to my Javascript program?

Tags: javascript

How do I add this API: http://developer.simsimi.com/api to my javascript script? I have the trial key, but I don't know how to add it in. Basically, when someone types '@Bot ***' the script should reply back to the '***' using the API. I just need to know how to incorporate the API into my script, I've searched up tutorials but I still don't understand how to do it.

Comment: **Edit:** Okay I found created this:  
i.imgur.com/QfTfC5z.png , but it comes up with `Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load (the sandbox.api... link) `  does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to call the api using HTTP GET Methods, look the URL they provided for trial version:

```
http://sandbox.api.simsimi.com/request.p?key=your_trial_key&lc=en&ft=1.0&text=hi
```

So you need to replace `your_trial_key` with your trial key you have, `text` with the key you want to use and then use HTTP GET in javascript to fetch the result and then show it on your page.

You can use is it in any library like React, Angular or jQuery for example, for get method in jQuery visit the link below:

https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp

Comment: I'm using this code:   {
      name: "Bot", 
            regex: /^bot/i,
            callback: function httpGet(theUrl) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open( "GET", "http://sandbox.api.simsimi.com/request.p?key=your_trial_key&lc=en&ft=1.0&text=hi", false ); // false for synchronous request
    xmlHttp.send( null );
                       sock.chat(xmlHttp.responseText);         
    return xmlHttp.responseText;
           }
        },  (I've removed the key) how do I get it to output it? My script uses sock.chat(text) to output text.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/QfTfC5z.png is coming up with the error Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load (the sandbox.api... link)